# Force pandas to store type information in output files

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm working with dataset which supposed to be pushed to external web-service. And that endpoint validates recieved `JSON` very strictly. While `pandas` treats types a bit more freely than it supposed to be.

For example, I need to push integer value as a text value to the web-service. Even if value was correctly serialized as `string` to `JSON` (with quotes around it), when it was read back `pandas` magically casts it back to integer.

Is there any way around this? Force pandas to store column type in output file? Or maybe be more strict during reading the data?

Maybe any other format is better for storing such data? Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you use the `dtype` parameter in [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html?highlight=dtype)?

Comment: If you working with JSON only, without any calculations, why not to get rid of pandas all together?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to perform transformations, and need to save data between the steps...

Comment: @Hoenie thank you, I have tired that just now, `dtype=True` does not make any difference. I believe it would be possible to solve the question by supplying dictionary with types and column names instead...

Comment: I posted an example as answer (doesn't fit as a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce `dtypes` while reading the data.

Example: considering the following JSON file called `t.json`:

```
{
  "Strings": {
    "A": "1",
    "B": "2"
  },
  "Integers": {
    "A": 3,
    "B": 4
  }
}
```

You can read the data, specifying the types in a `dict`:

```
df = pd.read_json('t.json', dtype={'Strings': str, 'Integers': str})
```

Which gives you the following dataframe:

```
    Strings Integers
  A       1        3
  B       2        4
```

and `df.dtypes` gives you:

```
Strings     object
Integers    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no explicit requirement to use `JSON` or `CSV`, it's also possible to use different, more advanced formats to store data.

[Feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather) seems to be most advanced according to the [comparison article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d), however I had a problem to roll it on `32-bit` version of python. So I ended up with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) serialization. It's supported by pandas out of the box. And it cost me only a slight variation from initial code:

```
# Dumping dataframe information to pickle file
df.to_pickle(path)

# Reading datafreame information from pickle file
df = pandas.read_pickle(path)
```

Types were kept untouched.